# Cast a non Activity class to Activity

Tags: android, menu, android-activity, jfreechart

I have a class that extends a DemoView class(to display some charts using afreechart library). My problem is I want to make a menu in that Activity, just a menu. I'm thinking about casting that class to Activity, is it logical? Or is there any other solution?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I never worked with afreechart library but you can only cast it to Activity if it already extends from that in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @GabrielNetto it extends View. So basically that's not possible to build a menu into that class?

Answer (score 3):

First basic check of [source code for DemoView](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart_sample/src/org/afree/chart/demo/DemoView.java?r=44) reveals that it inherits from [android.view.View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), which simply extends Object. So you should better *not* try what you described as:

> casting that class to Activity

If you want to add menu support, maybe you should try this architecture:

- extend DemoView and add menu support (like DemoViewWithMenu class)
- make your class extend DemoViewWithMenu instead of just DemoView

But if you simply try to access Activity object from within View object, you can utlilize the fact that Activity is also a Context. However not all Contexts are Activities, so the following may work but might also give you exceptions:

```
Activity a = (Activity)getContext();  //inside method of View class
```

See also:

- [get Activity object while in View context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901590/get-activity-object-while-in-view-context)
- [Access Activity class from View](http://www.41post.com/585/programming/access-activity-class-from-view)

Comment: Maybe you could also search for [Android get Activity from View object](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Android+get+Activity+from+View+object) in Google?

Comment: `extend DemoView and add menu support (like DemoViewWithMenu class)`: DemoViewWithMenu extends View too so adding a menu is impossible.