# How to properly terminate an activity from a custom view class?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3901590/6207504) post. Have a custom view (extends `EditText`) which must have the ability to call the `finish()` method of the parent activity if the user presses the END key.

How can I access the `activity` object of the host activity in order to call its `finish()` method from within the custom view class?

```
public class SuppressInputEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public SuppressInputEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SuppressInputEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SuppressInputEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode){
            case 6: //end key
                //todo: call finish() method of parent activity.
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

I can use the `getContext()` method of my class, available because it inherits from `view`, to get a context, but I don't know how to use that to access the `finish()` method. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Looking for a solution that can keep the class independent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the host i.e the activity where it's custom view is showing then you can do something like this.

```
(getContext() as? MainActivity)?.finish()
```

java

```
((MainActivity)getContext()).finish()
```

place this under try and catch

**Edit**: Create an interface which your Host activity implements and pass this as a listener yo your custom view then whenever needed to call this.

for ex.

```
interface CustomInputEditListener{
  public void onFinish();
}
```

in your Host activity implement this.

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity() implements CustomInputEditListener{

 //call this from onCreate()
  public void setHostListener(){
     suppressInputEditText.setHostEditListener(this);
  }

  @Override public void onFinish(){
      finish() ;
  }
}
```

in your SuppressInputEditText class create a method like this.

```
public void setHostEditListener(CustomInputEditListener listener){
  this.hostListener = listener;
}
```

and whenever you need to call finish just call

```
hostListener.onFinish();
```

Comment: my bad. shouldv'e mentioned that i'd like to keep the class independent. but thanks for the speedy response. (I'll update the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Cast `context` to `Activity` then call finish like below

Kotlin

```
(context as? Activity)?.finish()
```

Java

```
((Activity) context).finish()
```

Comment: thanks. I'd wrap in try / catch to keep independent and functional.