# Make button visible from SurfaceView?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

So basically I have an Activity with a layout that shows my custom SurfaceView and an invisible EditText.

How can I call setVisibility(VISIBLE) on that object? I do use post(Runnable...) on my SurfaceView object, but the problem is findViewById(my EditText id) returns null?

I found [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897466/585137) but how do I solve it?

Also, how do I recive a callback from the "Done" button on the EditText? Is it the same as the enter key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for id.content on the view that has it as a child. So use the following:

```
TextView t = (TextView) getParent().findViewById(R.id.contents);
```

To answer your other question, to find when the user hits the enter key, use

```
t.setOnEditorActionListener(...)
```